# SQLite and tkintetable

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to visualize a SQLite query using tkintertable, but I'm not sure how to format my results properly.

When I run this query

```
c.execute("SELECT type, effort FROM efforts WHERE datum =?", (time.strftime("%d:%m:%Y").replace(":", "."),))
```

I get an output like

```
[('type1', effort1), ('type2', effort2)]
```

tkintertable on the other hand requires an input like

```
{0: {'type': type1, 'effort': effort1}, 1: {'type': type2, 'effort': effort2}}
```

Is there any way to format the query output this way?

Comment: *"format the query output this way?"*: I'm not aware of doing so. You have convert the query output, which is `list` of `tuple`, to a `dict` of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @stovfl, you can't change explicitly tell the `cursor` object how to format its query output. You convert the query output returned by the cursor into your desired form afterwards.

As stated, your output is of the following: `[('type1', 'effort1'), ('type2', 'effort2')]`.
To convert this into a dictionary:

```
output = cursor.fetchall() #output from query
output_dict = {}
for index in range(len(output)): #use an index to create new dictionary elements
    data = output[index] #use that index to find the next piece of data to insert into output dictionary
    output_dict[index] = {'type':  data[0], 'effort': data[1]} #create new dictionary element, using 
    #the index as the key and setup a nested dictionary as the value associated with the key
```

Outputs:

```
0 {'type': 'type1', 'effort': 'effort1'}
1 {'type': 'type2', 'effort': 'effort2'}
```